# Can I use Italy Business Visa to travel to Sweden for tourism purpose

Tags: visas, schengen, change-purpose-of-travel

I have a valid Schengen Business Visa for Italy. I have already used this visa to travel to Italy for 31 days for business purpose. Total validity is 75 days with multiple entry.

Can I use the same visa to travel for tourism purpose to Sweden for 30 -35 days?

Comment: That's a somewhat odd visa to have, how come it's 75 days (and not either 35 or 90)? Did you business trip get shortened unexpectedly? How long is your visa's validity?

Comment: Sorry I misread, 75 days is the length of the validity period? What's the maximum duration of stay then?